# Windows does not boot automatically

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, laptop

- I have a samsung laptop NP350V5C
- I wanted to reinstall a Windows 7 home on it from a usb stick. After many tries (playing with boot options) I could not boot from USB.
- I then put the hard drive in another laptop (one that can boot from USB) and I successfully managed to format and install Windows 7 on the hard drive.
- New problem: when putting the hard drive back in the samsung laptop, it does not boot unless I press F10 and select the hard drive.
- Also this hard drive boots perfectly in my other laptop. And if I try the Hard drive of my other laptop in the samsung, it boots as well.

If anyone has a solution (or has ever seen something like this) so the samsung laptop boots nicely Windows with its own hard drive that would be great. Please let me know if I was not clear or if more details could help.

Comment: If the drive is the first in the boot priority then the problem is most probably related to the fact that the Os was installed while the HDD was connected to a different machine. You can try connecting the HDD back to the laptop windows was installed with and running [Sysprep](https://www.google.bg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiurrLD8rTIAhWCPj4KHSLoC-U&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftechnet.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fcc721940(v%3Dws.10).aspx&usg=AFQjCNHWfleNgoUYB3IejayXFMpgHwEGSA&sig2=QwQa6VWB6zzznAK1DHz2aw&bvm=bv.104819420,bs.2,d.dmo) before you move it again .

Answer (score 1):

Go into your BIOS on the computer that you have to press F10 and make sure the hard drive is listed in the boot device order / priority list (it may be called something similar to that).

If it's not, add it in there.  If it's in there, try moving it to the top of the list.

Comment: Yes the hard drive appears in the F10 menu, but not on top. Still, in the bios setup I already set it as boot priority 1.

Comment: @TomP This is a real stretch, but you could try removing all other devices from the boot priority list in the bios setup and perhaps see if that does the trick.